# Z-index not working with background image

Tags: html, css

For the following CSS -

```
.competition .banner .image {
    background: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}images/comp-banner.jpg") no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

And HTML -

```
    <div class="banner">
        <span class='image'>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <div class="main-info">
            {{ competition.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I cannot figure how to put the `description` on top of the background-image. I've tried setting the Z-index for all the `div`'s, `span`'s, etc. but nothing seems to work. How would I put the text on top of the background image here?

Comment: does the description have a position set?  Z-index only works if the element is set to a position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but the description is inside `main-info`... set `position: relative` to the main div and `position: absolute; z-index: 50` to the child... this should do it, than just do some `top`,`bottom`... to stay where it should

```
.info {
    background: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}images/comp-banner.jpg") no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    position: position absolute;
}
.main-info{
position: relative; z-index: 50;
}

    <div class="info">
        <div class="main-info">
            {{ competition.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
```